# Return ViewComponent from controller with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am trying to invoke a ViewComponent from a controller and pass along some parameters as anonymous objects in the following way:

```
public IActionResult Test(string pod, string start, string end)
{
    ServiceClient r2s = new R2S.ServiceClient();
    R2S.Konstant[] kData = r2s.GetKonstantListAsync(new string[] { "STATION" }, new string[] { pod }).Result; // mätarnummer in... --> alla konstanter kopplade till denna.

    return ViewComponent("MeterReader2", new { k = kData[0], fromDate = start, toDate = end });
}
```

My ViewComponent looks like this:

```
public class MeterReader2ViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Models.Konstant k, string fromDate, string toDate) // Endast en kanal.
    {
        code.... 
    }
 }
```

I´ve placed a breakpoint within the ViewComponent. When I run the code it does not break. However, If I just invoke the ViewComponent without passing along any values, it does break. Like this:

```
public IActionResult Test(string pod, string start, string end)
{
    ServiceClient r2s = new R2S.ServiceClient();
    R2S.Konstant[] kData = r2s.GetKonstantListAsync(new string[] { "STATION" }, new string[] { pod }).Result; // mätarnummer in... --> alla konstanter kopplade till denna.

     return ViewComponent("MeterReader2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you wouldn't return a ViewComponent in this fashion. Rather, you would create a View, and within that View's markup invoke the ViewComponent, passing it any relevant properties you may need.

Note: You have a synchronous method `Test` which call an asynchronous command `.GetKonstantListAsync`. Either go all synchronous, or change the method definition to make it asynchronous. (I will assume you want to keep it asynchronous, so I modified the method and added the `await` keyword.

In your Controller class:

```
public class MyController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string pod, string start, string end)
    {
        var r2s = new R2S.ServiceClient();
        R2S.Konstant[] kData = await r2s.GetKonstantListAsync(new string[] { "STATION" }, new string[] { pod }).Result;
        ViewData["start"] = start;
        ViewData["end"] = end;

        return View(kData);
    }
}
```

The ViewComponent:

```
namespace MyApp.ViewComponents
{
    public class MeterReader2ViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Models.Konstant k, string fromDate, string toDate) // Endast en kanal.
        {
            // code.... 
        }
    }
}
```

In Views\MyController\Task.cshtml

```
@using MyApp.ViewComponents;
@model RS2.Konstant[];

<h2>Here are some View Components!</h2>
@foreach (var konstant in Model) {
    @await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(MeterReader2ViewComponent ), new { k = konstant, fromDate = ViewData["start"], toDate = ViewData["end"]})
}
```

Apologies if my code isn't quite accurate, I'm not in front of Visual Studio at the moment to test it out.

Comment: I understand. I just tried this approach. If I create a view, which then invokes the ViewComponent with the new parameters, a new View is loaded correctly. However, I am currently within another ViewComponent already. How do I make the invoke to occur within the same viewcomponent view?

Comment: @Andrew Can you kindly check this thread please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75777025/how-to-download-the-coverted-doc-file-from-viewcomponent